# How to make words auto bold in Wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, bold

I have a wordpress site using woocommerce, I am addind product description like this:

A4TECH -  5.0 MEGA PIXEL "E" SERIES CAMERA WITHOUT MIC
Model: PK-335E
Warranty: 1 Year

Description:

5.0 MEGA PIXELS / DRIVER FREE/HI-SPEED USB 2.0 / 360 DEG. ROTATION/WITHOUT MIC

Price: Rs.1799/-

Every time I needs to bold these words

Model:
Model: 
Warranty: 
Description:
Price:

is there any trick that all these words auto bold?

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with same issue but I couldn't find a plugin that is working so I came up with a simple modification you can see [here](http://wpfreaks.com/capitalize-titles-wordpress-posts-pages-automatically/):

Comment: Its about Capitalizing Titles not what I am looking.